# mandatory argument with switch in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I want to have mandatory (must have) argument with a switch `--switch`.
But `argparse` interprete `--` as optional arguments and don't check for their existence.

Is there a way to fix that?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3    
import sys
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__file__)

# must have
parser.add_argument('--switch', metavar='switch', type=str)

sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [`required`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#required) argument:

```
parser.add_argument('--switch', metavar='switch', type=str, required=True)
```

Quoting the documentation:

> In general, the argparse module assumes that flags like `-f` and `--bar` indicate optional arguments, which can always be omitted at the command line. To make an option required, `True` can be specified for the `required=` keyword argument to `add_argument()`
>
> [...]
>
> **Note:** Required options are generally considered bad form because users expect *options* to be *optional*, and thus they should be avoided when possible.

Comment: And the argument will still be listed under the 'optional arguments' (non-positional) heading in the help.  `Usage` though will correctly indicate its required nature.  Despite the warning some people really do need/prefer the `required` parameter.